# ionic не проходят запросы к api на эмуляторе

Tags: ionic

Приложение отлично запускается и работает в браузере.
При попытке запустить приложение на эмуляторе, делаю запрос к api и получаю 404 ошибку.
В настройках указал:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

При этом, в браузере эмулятора, все работает хорошо. Запросы не проходят именно из приложения.

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобной проблемой?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему установкой плагина **cordova whitelist**.

В консоли:

```
ionic plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist.git
```

В config.xml добавил:

```
<allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
```